# bash script working, but outputting only 1 file

Tags: bash, shell-script

Attempting to have this script run through a directory and perform the operation on every file with the .tmp.tcx extension, so if I had 3 unique files with ${b}.tmp.tcx, I'm hoping for 3 unique files ${b}.tcx.

Unsure why this script ends up only outputting one file in .tcx (line 6).  Seems like a problem with line 5 defining b?

```
#! /bin/bash

for a in *tmp.tcx; do
  if [ -f "$a" ]; then # was it a file
    b="${a%.tmp.tcx}" #set b to $a without .tmp.tcx
    xml fo -t $a > "${b}.tcx"
    mv *gmn /home/pato/garmin/tcx-output/
    mv *tmp.tcx /home/pato/garmin/tcx-output/
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first entry into the loop for the first file does the xml output for the file it finds, then copies **all** tmp.tcx files out of the folder.  So the next go around the loop, the xml will try to process a file that is no longer there.

Try changing line 6 to

```
 mv $a /home/pato/garmin/tcx-output
```

Which will only move the file you just processed.